# How do I do this with Xcode 8.2.1?

Tags: xcode

Please help. I'm working on creating an app on Xcode 8.2.1. How do I create a screen where someone is able to put in their date of birth, time of birth (7:00am, etc) year of birth, and location of birth (country, state, and city) BUT then be able to press enter and depending on what exact information they put in, is what pops up on the NEXT screen, after they press enter. PLEASE help me or tell me about someone who can... thanks.

Comment: I really need help. Much appreciated.

Comment: What i have so far is "prototype cells" at the top of my screen, which I am not sure how to remove, and then I have a few text boxes on the screen that are supposed to be where you type in the information.

Comment: Hello hello....

Comment: I meant *what **code** do you have so far*?

Comment: I don't know how to write code for whatI'm trying to do, and I haven't written any so far, I just see what has been there all along

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is instantiate a ViewController class. Then, you want to create (with autoresizing masks set to false) three UITextFields and a UIButton and add them to the view controller's view. Then you want to write some logic that happens when you tap the button and then you want to let that logic determine when, if and what to pass to the next view controller. Then, you can pass that information to a placeholder parameter in the next view controller. Sorry, I can't be more specific but your question was kind of vague. Provide more information on what you've tried so far and I'm happy to help you figure this out.

Comment: Sorry, I never saw this comment. Are you able to help me find an answer to this question, because I still have not found an answer. Please email me at lydiazemanick@gmail.com if you can help. Thanks. I would really appreciate it.